# Validating BSB is a valid Australian BSB number

Tags: c#, http

How can I validate that a BSB number is a valid Australian BSB number?

Is there a way to programatically type in the BSB number into http://bsb.apca.com.au/public/BSB_DB.NSF/publicBSB.xsp and see if the response has success or something?

Comment: Have you been able to verify if [Search BSBs](http://bsb.apca.com.au/public/BSB_DB.NSF/publicBSB.xsp) provide either sort of web service or api for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question as asked: Yes, you can automate the filling of a web form and the clicking of a button. No, it's not worth the hassle of deconstructing their ajaxerific<sup>1</sup> web form.

The better solution would be to just grab the raw data from the [ACPA FTP server](ftp://apca.com.au/), and validate using that information. The files are conveniently available in TXT and CSV format. (At a glance the TXT format looks like it's tab-separated, but don't hold me to that.)

Alternatively you could click on the download BSB files link, which gives you the option to download the entire directory in one shot.

If I were developing this, I'd use the FTP option, pull all the data local, and validate locally.

*<sup>1</sup> Ajaxerific - Terrific Ajax. A term I just made up :)*